# How to imort IMS.db data to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Can any one guide me how i can import data of IMS.db to SQL Server 2008 R2?

I do have following files

1. IMS_C.db
2. IMS.log
3. IMS_Encrypt.txt

I am not able to identify what requires to import above files to SQL Server 2008 R2. It would be helpful if any one can guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is this tagged with db2?  This does not appear to be data coming from an IBM DB2 database.

Comment: Apology Ian. Thanks for the correcting me.